# NET Core web.api sudden memory peak after dozen of calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memory, .net-core

I have a web.api in .net core 3.1 that continually receives byte array data. I have noticed that after a dozen of calls, the memory suddenly increases with +100Mb.

[image]

As you can see in the GIF, the memory increases steadily as the calls are being handled. And then at 155Mb, the memory increases to 296Mb

I have created a repo: https://github.com/puppetSpace/MemoryIssue
This contains a client project, that calls the API continually.
And the web.api project, that gets the byte array from the body and waits 500ms (simulate work).
I just want to know a couple of things:
- Is someone else also getting this result?
- Is this normal behavior? like it's reserving memory? Or it's just because of debbuging?

I tried to use a profiler, but I can't figure out what causes the sudden increase.

Answer (score 1):

This should be related to your `MemoryStream`. After executing the MemoryStream, you need to `release` it, otherwise it will always occupy memory.

And because the `await` you are currently using is an asynchronous operation, you do not need to use `await Task.Delay(500);` to delay.

Modify your api code as follows：

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms).ContinueWith(x => ms.Dispose()); 
        return NoContent();
    }
```

Comment: If I do this. The memory immediately increases: https://imgur.com/a/xv1EgK5

Answer (score 1):

> *I tried to use a profiler, but I can't figure out what causes the sudden increase*

You can see there is yellow marked when the memory increased from 155 to 296 in the shared screenshot. It means that GC started of managed heap garbage collection. And when the first time running, it will initialize lots of object. You can take a snapshot before and after the GC for the detailed objects are created.

After that the memory is stabled, I am running the code sample about 6 minutes to monitoring the memory usage, you can refer the figure below:
[image]

Comment: Ah ok. So nothing to be worried about. It just the runtime doing it's thing. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: @SebastianSsw, Does this answer help you solve the issue? If so, please accept it as an answer, which will help people with similar problems to find the answer easier.